# Load of external html file has wrong behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i am loading a HTML file into a div using next code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#dialog-container').load("Dialog-Form.html");

});
```

But html code is disabled for Jquery functionalities, or CSS classes , i need that HTML loads only if i call it on page load.

If i put the code inside target page, html code works correctly, is listening Jquery, but if i load it from file, it fails.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#dialog-container').load("Dialog-Form.html");

});
    initFiltering('Table2bFiltered', 'gray');


</script>
<div id ="dialog-container">
```

Code in js file that is not working if i load hmtl from file.

```
  function initDialogForm(){
$(function () {

    var dialog, form,
        operador = $("#operador"),
        Value1 = $("#Value1"),
        AndOp = $("#AndOp"),
        OrOp = $("#OrOp"),
        operador2 = $("#operador2"),
        Value2 = $("#Value2"),
        allFields = $([]).add(operador).add(Value1).add(AndOp).add(OrOp).add(operador2).add(Value2),
        tips = $(".validateTips");
    dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Filtrar": function (){
                var andor = $('input[name=AndOp]:checked', '#dialog-form').val();
                CustomSorting($("#Value1").val(), $("#operador").val(), andor, $("#Value2").val(), $("#operador2").val());
                dialog.dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                dialog.dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            form[0].reset();
            allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
        }
    });

    form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

    });
}); }
```

HTML file code:

```
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Filtro Personalizado">
    <form>
           .....
    <form>    
</div>
```

Thaks for your help.

Comment: Is your issue simply that you're running the jQuery event attachments _before_ the HTML file is injected? Can you just move that code until _after_ the HTML is pulled in?

Comment: Hi, please have a read of the [tour] and [ask] (even though this is not your first question).  Also have a look at [mcve].  Only provide enough code to *reproduce* the issue.  20 `<option>` tags and multiple form fields just confuses things.

Comment: load() will not include stylesheets in current page if that's part of what you are suggesting as a problem. (problem statement is not very clear)

Comment: I can't understand the real problem, can you be more especific?

Comment: A: I load it from external file: (Jquery functions are useless, elements are not affected by events or functions)
B: I wirte HTML code inside the page: (Jquery works correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `.load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) has the ability to attach a callback. Run your jQuery event attachment code *after* the HTML has loaded so that the DOM elements are actually present to be attached to:

```
$('#dialog-container').load("Dialog-Form.html", () => {
  initFiltering('Table2bFiltered', 'gray');
  initDialogForm(); // Or whatever other code you need
});
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Have a nice day!